# Ошибка при считывании файла .txt в С#

Tags: c#

Пытался считать строку из текстового файла(в файле-"Now хорошая погода!"), но на выходе вместо кириллицы получил знаки вопроса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
try 
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader("D:\\test.txt"))
                {
                    //чтение файла
                    StringBuilder sb_2 = new StringBuilder(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    sr.Close();
                    for (int i = 0; i < sb_2.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(sb_2[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n файла.нет");
            }
```

Comment: Это проблема с кодировкой, в какой кодировке файл? Какая кодировка в консоли?

Comment: Кстати, файл прочитать в строку можно намного проще `string text = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.txt");` Зачем вывод в цикле? `Console.WriteLine(sb_2);`

Comment: кодировка - windows-1251

Comment: Сохраните файл в кодировке UTF-8, эта кодировка используется по умолчанию в C# для работы с файлами. Windows-1251 устарела и больше не используется нигде.

Comment: или читайте с [указанием кодировки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-string-system-text-encoding))

Comment: @aepot сохранил в UTF-8 все работает, спасибо большое